# Edit VSTS Wiki page via VSTS API

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to edit a VSTS wiki page via powershell and VSTS API and I am using [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wiki/pages/create%20or%20update?view=vsts-rest-4.1) as a reference.

When I try to edit an existing page, I get the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The page '<PAGE That I CREATED ALREADY>' specified in the add operation already exists in the wiki. Please specify a new page path.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Wiki.Server.WikiPageAlreadyExistsException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Wiki.Server","typeKey":"WikiPageAlreadyExistsException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

At line:32 char:11
+ $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -ContentType "appli ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I can create a new page with the content there, but I am stumped as how would I update an existing wiki page.  Please help.

Snippet of My Code:

```
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

    # updates wiki page

$uri = "https://$($vstsAccount).visualstudio.com/$($projectName)/_apis/wiki/wikis/$($wikiIdentifier)/pages?path=/$($existingPage)&api-version=4.1"

$body = @"
    {
        "content": "Hello"
    }
"@

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body -Verbose
```

Comment: Can you request the rest api successful after adding the header If-Match? And if your problem has been solved, you can mark the answer by clicking √ symbol on the left of the answer. And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

As the post [Update wiki page REST API can not working](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289074/update-wiki-page-rest-api-can-not-working.html) in developer community, please make sure `If-Match` is contained in request header.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different approach?

The storage for a VSTS Wiki is a Git repo (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/project/wiki/wiki-update-offline?view=vsts)). So you can clone the repo, change the files and push your changes back.

You can even use a VSTS build for this: the clone is implicit and there are many extensions to implement the push.

Comment: Having to edit the wiki as a series of git commands is a lot more friction than necessary. A wiki by definition is supposed to be extremely easy to edit - this is not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the page version is included in the request header. Refer to this link for details: [Pages - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wiki/pages/create%20or%20update?view=vsts-rest-4.1#edit_a_page).

> Version of the page on which the change is to be made. Mandatory for
>   **Edit** scenario. To be populated in the If-Match header of the request.